# What term captures "three groups"?

Tags: synonyms, terminology

Is there any one-word term that can capture the meaning of "three groups".

> For example, there are three groups of people in the world....

Comment: If the three groups share something in common, then, in a different way, they are one group.

Comment: I'd like to focus on the unshared features.

Comment: Are you looking for a fancy word? A noun? Your given sentence sounds fine to me. Any other term you'd probably want to reword the rest to get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The population is [tripartite](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tripartite)* would be applicable to your specific example.

More generally, I would refer to a **tripartite division** to avoid the (botanical) interpretation of a single organism with three connected lobes.